# Highcharts - Data won't get loaded into chart on Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, highcharts, webview

The configuration has been pre-tested on Fiddler and it's all working, but somehow it stopped working when i implemented it in Android's webview.

In my web interface class, I have a method which returns the data, and so I called the method in the HTML file in the script section as follow

```
var glucose = Android.getGlucoseData();
```

The debug console shows the following output of the glucose var (please don't mind the fake data)

> [
>   [Date.UTC(2016, 4, 02, 00, 00 ,00), 0.0],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 03, 00,
>   00 ,00), 0.0],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 04, 00, 00 ,00), 0.0],[Date.UTC(2016,
>   4, 05, 19, 16, 00), 8.65999984741211],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 06, 16, 55,
>   00), 9.65999984741211],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 06, 17, 19, 00),
>   3.6600000858306885],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 06, 17, 30, 00), 9.65999984741211],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 07, 00, 00 ,00), 0.0],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 08, 00, 00 ,00), 0.0]
>   ]

And when I passed it into the chart

```
series: [{
            name: 'Glucose',
            data: glucose,
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mmol/L'
            }
        }...
```

It does not render the data at all. **HOWEVER** if i do the following, which is essentially the same as the above, it **WORKS**.

> var glucose = [
>   [Date.UTC(2016, 4, 02, 00, 00 ,00), 0.0],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 03, 00, 00 ,00), 0.0],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 04, 00, 00 ,00), 0.0],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 05, 19, 16, 00), 8.65999984741211],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 06, 16, 55, 00), 9.65999984741211],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 06, 17, 19, 00), 3.6600000858306885],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 06, 17, 30, 00), 9.65999984741211],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 07, 00, 00 ,00), 0.0],[Date.UTC(2016, 4, 08, 00, 00 ,00), 0.0]
>   ]

From the above, you can realise i'm just literally hardcoding the data produced by Android.getGlucoseData(); into the variable.

May I know what did I do wrong?

Comment: The issue can be caused by using Date.UTC() in JSON, which is not evaluated when you load data. In other words, you cannot use functiosn in JSON. At the beginning, try to hardcode the timestamps (onyl for testing) and check if chart is printed or not.

Comment: You're right. I converted it to milliseconds since that is what Date.UTC will essentially produce and it works.

Comment: I posted my comment as correct answer.

Comment: Accepted! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be caused by using Date.UTC() in JSON, which is not evaluated when you load data. In other words, you cannot use functiosn in JSON. At the beginning, try to hardcode the timestamps (onyl for testing) and check if chart is printed or not.